# Should synonym suggestions be better promoted?

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-synonyms

Looking at the list of pending tag synonym suggestions that I'm allowed to vote on, I see 50 or so entries. Most of them have been there for months, waiting for the yay or nay. To get to that screen, you have to get through a rather baroque sequence of clicks.

I'm wondering if synonym suggestions should be better promoted, perhaps from the moderation tools screen. Hopefully this will clear the backlog.

It will also run the risk of more bad synonyms getting through, but if that's the case, then the voting mechanism needs revisiting.

Comment: Could you explain the baroque sequence of clicks, or link to the page? I didn't know a voting page existed, and I certainly don't know how to get there.

Comment: @ire: Go any tag page, click "Synonyms", click "See all synonyms", then "suggested"

Comment: I am also unable to propose or vote a synonym on a tag for which I don't have enough tag-specific reps. This makes imo no utter sense. It only grows the backlog. Previously this was not the case. I'd put the limit on user's own rep instead. >20K or something.

Answer (score 6):

I'd like to see something like this in the 10K Tools page. Ideally, sorted by tags that users have high upvotes in - it'd encourage users to make decisions on areas they are most familiar with.